# How to sum specific values in matrix?

Tags: matlab, matrix, sum

Example:
For this array:

```
A = [1    2    2    2     3    3  ; 
     0.1  0.2  0.3  0.05  0.2  0.8]
```

I'm searching for this answer:

For the first element `y(1) = 0.1`
2nd, 3rd, 4th `y(2) = 0.55`
5th and 6th `y(3) = 1`

How to do this?

Comment: yes sir its 0,55. I tried this way but i couldnt find the answers that im searching for
Thank you

ind1 = A(1,:) == 1;
ind2 = A(1,:) == 2;
ind3 = A(1,:) == 3;

      A1 = A(:,ind1)
A2 = A(:,ind2)
A3 = A(:,ind3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function x = sum_elements(A,n)
    [~,col]=find(ismember(A,n));
    x = sum(A(2,col));
end
```

Call the function with the matrix and the element n.

```
sum_elements(A,1) = 0.1000
sum_elements(A,2) = 0.5500
sum_elements(A,3) = 1
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`accumarray`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html).

```
A = [1    2    2    2     3    3  ; 
 0.1  0.2  0.3  0.05  0.2  0.8]

accumarray(A(1,:).',A(2,:).')
```

Comment: You might want to make a note that the default function of `accumarray`, when not specifying one, is `@sum` and that that's why this works. Smart solution!